# How to convolve rgb picture?

Tags: python

I've tried to use this code to blur the picture, but somehow the picture appears with different color and also the effect doesn't apply to the picture. Here is the code that I've made.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def filterkonvolusi(gambar, kernel):
    kernel_size=len(kernel)
    row=gambar.shape[0]-kernel_size+1
    col=gambar.shape[1]-kernel_size+1
    dim=gambar.shape[2]-kernel_size+1

    result=np.zeros(shape=(row,col,dim))
    for m in range(dim):
        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(col):
                current=gambar[i:i+kernel_size, j:j+kernel_size]
                multiplication=np.sum(current*kernel)
                div=np.sum(kernel)
                result[i,j,m]=np.floor(abs(multiplication/div))
    return result

img=cv2.imread('unnamed.jpg')
gambar=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
kernel=([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])

filtered=filterkonvolusi(gambar,kernel)
plt.imshow(filtered)
plt.show()
```

Comment: create small image, calculate all on paper and later compare (step by step) with values calculated by code. And use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments.

Comment: I don't understand why you use smaller `dim`. And if you use smaller `row` then why you use `range(row)` and not `range(1, row+1)` to skip first and last element. And your kernel replaces top left pixel in kernel instead of center pixel.

Comment: @furas Can you help me to figure out the right code? I'm actually a little bit confused with this problem. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: first I would check if `cv2` doesn't have already function to `blur` it with own `kernel`

Comment: see OpenCV: [Smoothing Images](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) - it will run much faster then `for`-loops.